# Trying to access webmethod from android app using OkHttp3

Tags: java, android, web-services, okhttp

I'm trying to use the following code to create a webmethod and then using it from an android app using OkHttp:

**webservice** hosted at http://*someaddress*.com/HelloWorld

```
using GLS.GLIS.Core;
using System.IO;
using GLS.GLIS.ApplicationServices.Settings;

namespace GLS.GLIS.Web.Ax
{

  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
  // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
  public class Wireless : System.Web.Services.WebService
  {

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Above works, production code

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.whirlpool.ad.na.gruves1.glisweb">

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.whirlpool.ad.na.gruves1.glisweb;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button HelloWorldbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    HelloWorldbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onHelloWorld(v);
        }
    });
  }



  public void onHelloWorld (View v) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://<someaddress>.com/HelloWorld")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

The goal is to use the android app to hit the webservice HelloWorld and onResponse, toast "Success". My goal is to build on this in future iterations and utilize more webservices. However, the following keeps returning various errors that, when searched, don't return solutions related to my issue. The best I can come up with at the moment is that it maybe an activity issue. Breaking the code and following the stack trace doesn't return anything that stands out to me either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

The following is the error I get when running in an emulator:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
  Process: glisweb, PID: 2749
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:345)
  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:259)
  at glisweb.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:54)
  at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
  at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me quite a bit of experimentation and poking around but I finally found the solution to this error. The gist of this solution is that you should be careful what code you put in your onFailure and onResponse methods within your newCall function. For example:

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Within onResponse, using the function toast.show() throws the particular error I was seeing. I believe this has something to do with the Views Android uses. Simply remove this code and replace it with a variable that can the be referenced outside of the onResponse method.